# Opsview Slave Server not sending out emails

Tags: opsview

I successfully installed and connected 2 slaves to my master server. The problem is, neither are sending out alerts and the Postfix logs on both are empty. The "Run On" option is also set to "Slave" on the Master server.
What could I possibly miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sudo su – nagios
nlcat |grep NOTIF

would give me this:

> Thu Apr 14 13:43:43 2016: wproc: NOTIFY job 114 from worker Core
>   Worker 9378 is a non-check helper but exited with return code 255

What was missing was installing the Mail package.

Also if you're using Ubuntu dont forget to alter the default sending script from /usr/bin/Mail to /usr/bin/mail.

Cheers